# Creating a search in php - typing in a city and getting the attractions for that city listed below

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a database in phpMyAdmin. I want to create a search so it will display tourist attractions. So for example if I type in London the Big Ben will appear, as well as a number of other tourist attractions in London. I want to be able to type in a city and then tourist attractions for that city will appear below.

All the search tutorials I have looked at only retrieve data from one table, and I am retrieving it from two.

I have a table called city, and in that table there is city_id and city_name

I have a second table called attractions and in that table there is city_id, tourist_id, attraction_name, latitude, longitude and cost.

I would like to be able to create a search so when I type in the city_name the  attraction_name, latitude, longitude and cost appears. However I don't know how to link these two tables together in the mysql_query. If anyone could help me that would be really great. Thanks

```
<?php
require_once('config1.php');
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zz_attractions INNER JOIN city on zz_attractions.city_id = zz_city.city_id where zz_city.city_name = ? LIKE '%searchq%'") or die("could not search");
$count = mysql_num_rows ($query);
if ($count == 0) { 
    $output = 'there was no search results';
} else {
    while $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $attraction_name = $row['attractionname'];
    $lat = $row['latitude'];
    $long = $row['longitude'];
    $cost = $row['cost'];

    $output .= '<div>'.$attraction_name.' '.lat'. '.long.' '.cost.'</div>';

    }
?>
```

Comment: Show your codes

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a "join" query. That looks a little something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

In your case that query might look like

```
SELECT * FROM attractions INNER JOIN city on attractions.city_id = city.city_id where city.city_name = ?
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I am literally just starting so it will take me a while to get the search up and running but will try this code and the code above as see if any of these work for me

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBLuP2JZcEg and added your code in to the $query. I am currently getting an error 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in SEARCH.PHP FILE on line 8. Do you know what that means?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that sounds like a PHP error, like you don't have the mysql library setup in php correctly. I don't know much about PHP, so I'm not sure exactly what to do. That should probably be a separate question since it's unrelated to the issue of getting data from two tables.

Comment: Ok I am new to this, so I am not sure how it works, but thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a link between the two tables, using an unique value which is present in both: extra, we have city_id !

So, what you have to do know, is get the values you want using this id.

You have the name of a city, linked to an unique id, and this id brings you to a list of tourist attractions.

You have to make two SQL resquests:
- Get the city_id depending on city_name
- Get the data using this city_id

One solution is to use subquery :

```
SELECT attraction_name, latitude, longitude, cost FROM attractions WHERE city_id IN (SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE city_name ILIKE 'London');
```

Comment: I think a subquery in this case might not perform as well as using an inner join.

Comment: Thanks so much, I am literally just starting so it will take me a while to get the search up and running but will try this code and the code below to see if any of these work for me

Answer (score 0):

There're more ways how to implement your search. Really easy example for start is to use some autoComplete. You can use Bootstrap TypeAhead or as in and example jQuery EasyAutocomplete.

```
var options = {
    url: function(phrase) {
        return "http://yourSearchUrl.com/search/?query=" + phrase;
        },
        list: {
            onChooseEvent: function() {
                var item = $(".autocomplete").getSelectedItemData();
                //fill your additional search form with ID for submit
                //$("#input-qId").val(item.id);
                //or redirect to page with attraction
                window.location.href = "http://yourPage.com/attraction/?id=" + item.id;
            }
        },
        template: {
            type: "custom",
            method: function(value, item) {
                //custom template for autocomplete container
                return "<span data-id='" + item.id + "'>" + item.value + "</span>";
            }
        },
        getValue: "value" //defines array index with value
    };

//your input selector
$(".autocomplete").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

For your search page you can return JSON array from select then. Two possible scenarios for search. When user type "Lo" you can show list of cities.

```
SELECT city_id, city_name FROM city WHERE city_name LIKE %get_url_phrase%;
```

Second scenario you search after submitting full city name. Also can return result by just partial city name.

```
SELECT * FROM attractions WHERE city_id IN (SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE city_name LIKE %get_url_phrase%);
```

If you search first just for city, then you can pass city_id to attraction search page and perform query

```
SELECT * FROM attractions WHERE city_id = "cityIdParam"
```

Possible to match sql query on exact phrase match, city_name = "London", fulltext search, in second query use table JOIN. Like clause just for example, not good performance at all.

The result JSON would be in form like:

```
[{"id": 1, "value": "AttractionName"}]
```

If you provide me with more accurate info about implementation i can answer you more :)

Comment: So for the javascript part will I add this to the js file I have? And then create a php search, how will I link these two pages? I am just going to have my php in my search.html file, but will change it to search.php

Comment: You can add JS code to javascript file and include on place where's your current page html template. Then just edit links to your search page. On search page, get parameter from URL ($_GET['phrase']) and pass to sql query. Return response as application/json with data.